# create hyperlink to file server in pipeline jobs console

Tags: jenkins, hyperlink, jenkins-pipeline

I want to print a hyperlink to a file I created while running a pipeline job. This simple .txt file should be opened after hitting the link. I found [this wiki entry](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Hyperlinks+in+HTML) but there is no example implementation. Is there a way to perform this? I dont know how to trigger the 'explorer' call. (this is for windows use only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used : `'<file://link/to/folder/>'` and its working ;)